# Easiest way to create a Subversion Repository and manage batch creation?

Tags: svn

We wrote batch files a while ago that automatically creates Subversion Repositories. Due to someone else's mistake, we lost the batch files. These batch files were at least 50 hours worth of work to set up.

Now, before I proceed and redo these batch files, I was wondering if there is an easy way or perhaps a program that can:

1. Automatically copy an existing Subversion repo into a new repo
2. Modify various config files to include new login details and passwords
3. Automatically deploy to a server
4. Is there something like this?

Comment: Next time, put you SVN batch files under SVN ;-)

Comment: `svnmirror` can copy an existing repo, but something is telling me you are solving the wrong problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think, Server Fault was and is a better place for such type of question

Comment: Pease, describe your **business-task in simple words**, not half-made solution: I, as @tripleee, can't imagine, where cloning SVN-repo and changing ACL is required as ordinary every-day process

Comment: Also, this would be a lot easer with a distributed VCS. If you don't like Git, have a look at Mercurial (or bzr, or Darcs, or Monotone, or a number of others).